# Parameter into commandhandler

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, icommand

I've inherited some code that implements WPF Commands as follows:

```
    public ICommand pvToggleSelectMapCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new CommandHandler(() => pvToggleSelectMap(), true);
        }
    }
```

This is fine without parameters and doesn't use a generic RelayCommand-like class to set up the command handling. I need to put a parameter into this now, and am struggling to find a simple way to handle on using this way of command handling.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Post code for CommandHandler class. Is this you own custom class or  coming from some framework?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when using some form of `delegate ICommand`, you can just add an `object` input parameter to get your `CommandParameter` object.  Try this:

```
public ICommand pvToggleSelectMapCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new CommandHandler((params) => pvToggleSelectMap(params), true);
    }
}
```

...

```
public void pvToggleSelectMap(object params) { ... }
```

Of course, this *might* not work with your `CommandHandler` class as you didn't provide any information for that here.